# Can one copy their own code from a different company?

Tags: legal, source-code, ethics

Lets say someone has written code for multiple companies that have then copyrighted you work. Another company gives them a similar project to one they have worked on previously. Would it be legal for them to copy their own previous work and submit it their current company?

Is Coping ones own work and using it for a different company unethical? Are there any consequences of this action?

Comment: If you're an employee (or a contractor with a copyright-assignment clause in your contract), it's your *employer's* work, not yours.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "copy" here? Do you mean actually copy and pasting, or do you mean that you remember how the code looked like and can roughly reproduce it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reuse generic code for consulting between companies?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131103/how-can-i-reuse-generic-code-for-consulting-between-companies) - it is not literally the same question, but similar enough to make the top answer apply here as well.

Comment: Copy and Pasting

Comment: "*Is Coping ones own work*". But it's not "ones own work" as you previously stated "*...companies that have then copyrighted you[r] work...*", so it's their work. You can only copy material with the permission of the copyright holder.